# Which of the following spaces are completely normal?

Tags: general-topology

From Munkre books , page no: $205$

Which of the following spaces are completely normal?

$(a)$ A subspace of a completely normal space

$(b)$ The product of two completely normal spaces.

$(c)$ A well-ordered set in the order topology.

$(d)$ A metrizable space.

$(e)$ A compact Hausdorff space.

$(f)$ A regular space with a countable basis.

$(g)$ The space $\mathbb{R_l}$

Any hints/solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Of course, by definition: if every subspace of $X$ is normal the same holds for every subspace $A$ of $X$ (as a subspace of $A$ is also one of $X$, hence normal).

(b) No, by the example 2 on page 203 ($\omega_1 \times (\omega_1+1)$ in usual modern notation and $S_\Omega \times \overline{S}_\Omega$ in Munkres' notation) and the fact that all sets in the order topology are completely normal:

(c) Yes, follows from 32.4. In fact all subspaces of ordered spaces are normal.

(d) Yes, metrisable spaces are normal, and metrisability is hereditary.

(e) No, as  witnessed by $[0,1]^J$ with $J$ uncountable, which contains the non-normal subspace $(0,1)^J$. You can also use $\overline{S}_\Omega \times \overline{S}_\Omega$ and re-use example (b).

(f) Such spaces are metrisable (if $T_1$, by the Urysohn metrsiation theorem), so yes. Or use that such spaces are normal (even without $T_1$) and that both properties are hereditary. So the proof is slightly different in both cases.

(g) I presume you mean $\mathbb{R}_l$, the lower limit topology on the reals. 
This is indeed completely normal, as it's homeomorphic to the subspace $(0,1) \times \{0,1\}$ of the ordered square (which is ordered hence completely normal).

Comment: @ henno  sir thanks a lots  sir,,,,,i see  ur  articles  in topology atlas,,,it was not wriiten clearly

Comment: sir i have   confusion  in option  a)  if i take  open subspace  then , it  will not completely normal ??  Pliz  clarified  this

Comment: @jasmine If $X$ is completely normal this is equivalent to the fact that **all** subspaces of $X$ are normal. This includes all subspaces of any subspace of $X$ (as being a subspace of is a transitive relation).

Comment: okkss  thanks  u @henno sir

Comment: Is there a way to solve $b$ without using any later parts? (you used part c in this case)